# Symfony - add multiple images in association

Tags: php, twig, symfony

Hello I'm learning Symfony 3 and i Have this problem that I have an Entity Projects and an entity ProjectImages and relations is one to many.

Now I want to add f.e 4 images to one project and I don't know how to do it.

I read the documentation, how to add files etc. But how to add file in association in one FOrm where I create project ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use form collection here is examples.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html